# Appending Series in Python

Tags: python, pandas, append, series

I'm trying to append a Series in Panda, but the output that I get is not the one that I want.
I'm just testing this to see if I can read a file and output the parts that I want into a DataFrame composed of different series, and then append the series together into a DataFrame

Below the test code for this. Thank you in advance for you help and consideration

```
s = pd.Series([32, 434, 542, 'BC2'])
d = pd.Series(['B1', 'B3', 'B4', 123, 43, 54])
result = pd.DataFrame({'s': s, 'd':d})
print result 
print '\n'
d.append(s)#.reset_index(drop=True)
print d
print '\n'
print s
```

and this is the result

```
    d    s
0   B1   32
1   B3  434
2   B4  542
3  123  BC2
4   43  NaN
5   54  NaN


0     32
1    434
2    542
3    BC2
dtype: object
```

Desired output:

```
  0 32
  1 434
  2 542
  3 BC2
  4 B1
  5 B3
  6 B4
  7 123
  8 43
  9 54
```

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: Do you just want to add a new column? For instance are you after `pd.concat([s,d], axis=1)`?

Comment: Sorry About that, I just updated the question to show the desired output. and no I'm trying to append one column at the end of another column

concat essentially the same thing as `result = pd.DataFrame({'s': s, 'd':d})`

Comment: So what's wrong with `s.append(d).reset_index(drop=True)`?

Comment: I get the same result as what I get with `s.append(d)` 
I should say that the index reset isn't the issue here, the issue is that d simply doesn't get added to s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are answering your question yourself. Check your code:

```
new_df = s.append(d).reset_index(drop=True)
print new_df

0     32
1    434
2    542
3    BC2
4     B1
5     B3
6     B4
7    123
8     43
9     54
```

Comment: Thank you, I guess I didn't think to re-declare the series. Sorry and thank you

Comment: I have another question, is it possible to copy elements from list that is not a panda series or list into a panda series? I'm basically writing a script to run through a file and pick things from the file and copy them into a Series, but for the read-from file portion i'm merely using regular string read and splitting them

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for, but i'm sure it is possible. You could create pandas series out of almost anything..